# How can I fill text continously into a tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I create numbers in a loop. At stdout you can watch the progress, because there is a print statement in the loop. But I want to make the progress visible in a tkinter text widget. So at each print I also copy the new number into a text widget. But in the text widget the numbers first show, when the loop stops.

```
import tkinter as tk
def count():
    number = 0
    while number<10000:
        number += 1
        print(number)
        text.insert(tk.END, number)
        text.see(tk.END)
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.grid()
button = tk.Button(root, text="run", command=count)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I expected to see the numbers in the text widget in a similar way they show at stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this one of them is this.

You can use the `.after` method to do this

```
import tkinter as tk

def count(number):
    print(number)
    text.insert(tk.END, number) # or text.insert(tk.END, str(number) + '\n') to put a newline after each number
    if number < 10000: # change 10000 to whatever you want
        # Schedule the next update after 1 millisecond
        root.after(1, count, number + 1)

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.grid()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=lambda: count(0))
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Second way is to use `Threading`

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
def count():
    number = 0
    while number<10000:
        number += 1
        print(number)
        text.insert(tk.END, number) # text.insert(tk.END, str(number) + '\n') to add a newline after each number
        text.see(tk.END)


def supportFunction():
    t = Thread(target=count)
    t.start()
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.grid()
button = tk.Button(root, text="run", command=supportFunction) # Calling supporter function
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I prefer the solution with threading, as it does not slow down the counting by "after".

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want - I've set it up to print each number on a new line, and cancel the `after` loop once the count is complete

```
import tkinter as tk


def count():
    global number  # allow this function to modify the value of 'number'

    loop = root.after(10, count)
    if number < 10000:
        number += 1
        text.insert(tk.END, str(number) + '\n')
        text.see(tk.END)
    else:
        number = 0  # reset
        root.after_cancel(loop)


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.grid()
button = tk.Button(root, text="run", command=count)
button.grid()
number = 0  # declare the starting value globally instead of inside 'count'
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: bro it will give error `cannot access local variable 'loop' where it is not associated with a value`

Comment: so add `loop` to global and one more thing in else change `number=0` so user can click again the button.

Comment: @codester_09 it doesn't need to exist outside of `count`, so why bother with the `global`?

Comment: nah I don't mean that, but Okay.